# Finding a minimal solution to a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to find an efficient algorithm to solve the following
problem.

Let $AX = B$ be a system $n$ of linear equations,
where $A$ is a matrix with $n$ rows, $m$ columns of rank $m < n$,
$B$ is a column vector of length $n$, and $X$ is a vector of
variables of length $m$.

We can find a least squares solution.  It should also possible to select
a number of subsystems of $m$ equations from the original system, so that
each subsystem has an exact solution.

I would like to find a subsystem of equations that gives a minimal solution $X$
(assuming it exists), in the following sense.   A solution $X$ is less than a
solution $Y$ when for any $i$, $x_i <= y_i$.

I can't unfortunately elaborate on any attempts I made to solve this
because I really have no idea in which direction to look.

Thank you for any hints or ideas.